# Recompile build.sbt and project/ before testOnly

Tags: scala, sbt

My structure of scala project is pretty simple:

```
/someApp
  /scala
     /project
        Dependencies.scala
        ...
     /main
        ...
     /test
       MyTest.scala
  /target
     ...
  build.sbt
```

Now, let's consider:

```
sbt> testOnly *MyTest
```

It recompiles `MyTest.scala` and executes it as I expect. However, when I introduce changes to `build.sbt` or `project/Dependencies.scala` it ignores these changes.

Could someone explain me and understand why does it happen? The `sbt` seems to be one huge mystery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include changes made to `.sbt` files or `.scala` files under the project folder, you'll need to run the `reload` command within the sbt shell.

You can also force sbt to reload each time it detects a change in these files by adding this line to your `build.sbt`:

```
Global / onChangedBuildSource := ReloadOnSourceChanges
```